# Why are all the answers for my javascript quiz come back as wrong?

Tags: javascript

No matter which answer I select my answer always comes back as wrong. Im not sure where the issue is, I think its because I have an event listener on each button to check the answer.

Here is the code for how I get my elements

```js
var questionLocation = document.getElementById("questionLocation")
var answerA = document.getElementById("answerA")
var answerB = document.getElementById("answerB")
var answerC = document.getElementById("answerC")
var answerD = document.getElementById("answerD")

window.addEventListener("load", function pullRandom() {
  let randomQ = myQuestions[Math.floor(Math.random() * myQuestions.length)];
  console.log(randomQ)

  questionLocation.innerHTML = randomQ.Question;
  answerA.innerHTML = randomQ.answers.a;
  answerB.innerHTML = randomQ.answers.b;
  answerC.innerHTML = randomQ.answers.c;
  answerD.innerHTML = randomQ.answers.d;
  var correct = randomQ.correctAnswer;
  console.log(correct)
```

These are my buttons

```html
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
  <div id="questionHolder" style="display: block;">
    <h4 id="questionLocation"></h4>
    <div id="answers">
      <div id="answerA" class="btn btn-dark"></div>
      <div id="answerB" class="btn btn-dark"></div>
      <div id="answerC" class="btn btn-dark"></div>
      <div id="answerD" class="btn btn-dark"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are a sample of my question array

```js
const myQuestions = [{
    Question: "What alloy is Captain America's sheild made of?",
    answers: {
      a: "Steel",
      b: "Adamantium",
      c: "Vibrainium",
      d: "Uru"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    Question: "What was the code name of the Government project that gave Captain America his powers?",
    answers: {
      a: "Weapon X",
      b: "Super Soldier",
      c: "AIM",
      d: "Hyrda"
    },
    correctAnswer: "b"
  },
  {
    Question: "What was the name of the Virtual Intellegnce designed by Iron man?",
    answers: {
      a: "Jarvis",
      b: "Hal 9000",
      c: "T-800",
      d: "R2-D2"
    },
    correctAnswer: "a"
  },
  {
    Question: "What did Iron man build to power his suits and keep himself alive?",
    answers: {
      a: "Skynet",
      b: "Death Star",
      c: "Gamma Bomb",
      d: "Arc Reactor"
    },
    correctAnswer: "d"
  }
]
```

And these are the event listeners I have to check the answer

```js
answerA.addEventListener("click", function checkAnswers(answer) {
  if (correct == answerA) {
    alert("Correct!")
    score++;
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!")
    console.log(score)
  }
});

answerB.addEventListener("click", function checkAnswers(answer) {
  if (correct == answerB) {
    alert("Correct!")
    score++;
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!")
    console.log(score)
  }
});

answerC.addEventListener("click", function checkAnswers(answer) {
  if (correct == answerC) {
    alert("Correct!")
    score++;
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!")
    console.log(score)
  }
});

answerD.addEventListener("click", function checkAnswers(answer) {
  if (correct == answerD) {
    alert("Correct!")
    score++;
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!")
    console.log(score)
  }
});
```

I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`if( correct == answerA ){` compares a string (`correct`) with the **HTML element** for the answer (`answerA), not its text.

If you want to keep using `answerA` (`answerB`, etc.) for this comparison, then:

Given that you're setting the answer using `innerHTML`, you could use `innerHTML` for the comparison:

```
if( correct == answerA.innerHTML){
```

**but**, the HTML you get back from a browser may vary from the HTML you specify for it. If you want to get back exactly the text you put on it, you could store it in an attribute. Also, unless you really want to put HTML in the answers, use `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`:

```
answerA.textContent = randomQ.answers.a;
answerA.setAttribute("data-answer", randomQ.answers.a);
```

Then later

```
if( correct == answerA.getAttribute("data-answer")){
```

---

That said, I don't think I'd compare with the HTML element at all. I'd compare with the question's answers instead:

```
if( correct == randomQ.answers.a){
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following:

1. Know your choices a, b, c, d, etc...
2. Add data attributes to each HTML choice for quick look-up
3. Add the event listeners to each of the elements; up-front
4. Retrieve a random question
5. Populate the `textContent` of each "button"
6. Check the answer by comparing data attribute to the correct choice

This introduces looping to dynamically set-up the content of the question form.

Checking the answer is now as simple as:

```js
e.target.dataset.choice === randomQ.correctAnswer
```

```js
const myQuestions = getQuestions();
const choices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let score = 0;
let randomQ = null;

const main = () => {
  choices.forEach(x => {
    document.getElementById('answer' + x.toUpperCase())
      .addEventListener('click', checkAnswers)
  });

  prepareQuestion();
};

const prepareQuestion = () => {
  randomQ = retrieveRandomQuestion(myQuestions);
  const questionLocation = document.getElementById("questionLocation");
  questionLocation.innerHTML = randomQ.Question;
  choices.forEach(x => {
    var choice = document.getElementById('answer' + x.toUpperCase());
    choice.textContent = randomQ.answers[x];
  });
}

const checkAnswers = (e) => {
  if (e.target.dataset.choice === randomQ.correctAnswer) {
    alert("Correct!");
    score++;
    prepareQuestion(); // Ask another random question
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!");
    console.log(`Final score: ${score}`);
  }
}

const retrieveRandomQuestion = (questions) =>
  questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];

main();

// Convenience function to retrieve data above...

function getQuestions() {
  return [{
    Question: "What alloy is Captain America's sheild made of?",
    answers: {
      a: "Steel",
      b: "Adamantium",
      c: "Vibrainium",
      d: "Uru"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  }, {
    Question: "What was the code name of the Government project that gave Captain America his powers?",
    answers: {
      a: "Weapon X",
      b: "Super Soldier",
      c: "AIM",
      d: "Hyrda"
    },
    correctAnswer: "b"
  }, {
    Question: "What was the name of the Virtual Intellegnce designed by Iron man?",
    answers: {
      a: "Jarvis",
      b: "Hal 9000",
      c: "T-800",
      d: "R2-D2"
    },
    correctAnswer: "a"
  }, {
    Question: "What did Iron man build to power his suits and keep himself alive?",
    answers: {
      a: "Skynet",
      b: "Death Star",
      c: "Gamma Bomb",
      d: "Arc Reactor"
    },
    correctAnswer: "d"
  }];
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #112;
}

#questionHolder {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

#answers {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.btn {
  flex: calc(50% - 2em);
  width: 8em;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.25em;
  text-align: center;
  border: thin solid #557;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-dark {
  background: #225;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn-dark:hover {
  background: #ED0;
  color: #000;
}

.btn-dark:active {
  background: #F70;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
  <div id="questionHolder" style="display: block;">
    <h4 id="questionLocation"></h4>
    <div id="answers">
      <div id="answerA" class="btn btn-dark" data-choice="a"></div>
      <div id="answerB" class="btn btn-dark" data-choice="b"></div>
      <div id="answerC" class="btn btn-dark" data-choice="c"></div>
      <div id="answerD" class="btn btn-dark" data-choice="d"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `if( correct == answerA )`, you are comparing an HTML element

`var answerA = document.getElementById("answerA")`

with a string

`var correct = randomQ.correctAnswer;`

This is not a valid comparison, but there are multiple ways to achieve your goal: use the element's `textContent` to compare strings `var answerA = document.getElementById("answerA").textContent`, use the element's id `var answer = answer.target.id.split("answer")[1]` or use data-attributes like @T.J. Crowder suggested in his answer. (and probably more..)

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted...? (Yes, perhaps a bit vague about how to fix it, but not *wrong*.)

Comment: I've edited my answer to add more details, maybe this will help